# Deploying .net core app to heroku docker fails at dotnet restore

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment, dockerfile, github-actions

I am trying to deploy [this project](https://github.com/distractor/glista-api) (branch glider) to Heroku. the project is written in .net core 5.0 and I have created a YML script for github actions:

```
name: Heroku

on: [push]

jobs:
  deploy_glista:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build and deploy the Docker image
      env: 
        HEROKU_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_USERNAME }}
        HEROKU_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}
        APP_NAME: ${{ 'glista' }}
      run: |
        docker login --username=$HEROKU_USERNAME --password=$HEROKU_API_KEY registry.heroku.com
        heroku container:push web -a $APP_NAME
        heroku container:release web -a $APP_NAME
```

accompanied with Dockerfile:

```
# NuGet restore
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln .
COPY Test/*.csproj Test/
COPY Core/*.csproj Core/
COPY Api/*.csproj Api/
RUN dotnet restore "Api/Glista.Api.csproj"
COPY . .

# testing
FROM build AS testing
WORKDIR /src/Api
RUN dotnet build
WORKDIR /src/Test
RUN dotnet test

# publish
FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /src/Api
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /src/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /src/publish .
# ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
# heroku uses the following
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet Api.dll
```

For the sake of testing, the deployment is executed on every push. Anyway, something goes wrong when `dotnet restore` is called from the Dockerfile. It seems I can't get pass the following error:

```
/src/Api/Glista.Api.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.5.1' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
  Failed to restore /src/Api/Glista.Api.csproj (in 9.04 sec).
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "Api/Glista.Api.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
 ▸    Error: docker build exited with Error: 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

As I am unexperienced with Docker and since I wasn't able to google any useful solutions, does anybody have an idea what is wrong with my deployment script or docker file?

Comment: There are a [GitHub issue open](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491)

Comment: @Max That basically means there is not much I can do until it's fixed? Noooot happy.